# How to visualize a 16-bit grayscale image with cv2.imshow()?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a set of grayscale drone images in `tiff` format having 16-bit resolution where a person can be seen moving. How can I visualize these images in OpenCV as a normal image, so that I can see the information within the image in OpenCV? Currently, when I try to read and show the image, I see a black image.

```py
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"],IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

cv2.imshow("image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have tried the above code, but it still displays a complete black image. However, when I convert the image to a `png` and then use the above code, then it works fine which I do not want to do due to loss of information.

Here is the link to sample image. All images contain different information.

https://filebin.net/n3oidsqn70eq8a9x/gelmer_gas_0_Raw_316_4245_2942_1455208775.tif?t=c2m8vnsn

The image should be like the below. This was opened with another software just for visual purpose

[image]

Comment: The code above does not display any image. How do you display the image? Please simply show all your code. Did you try to inspect the variable `image` with a debugger? What is the dataformat of the image?

Comment: @M.Spiller updated the question

Comment: If you now would also post one of the images you have problems with, we could help you.

Comment: @M.Spiller unfortunately when i upload the image here or any other platform, it's automatically converted to a `png` so that is why i am not sharing it

Comment: Dropbox or any other file sharing platform? Put it into a zip before uploading?

Comment: Your problem is that the images are in 16b and imshow shows only in 8b of 1,3,4 channels. For displaying purposes, you can try one of two things: 1) [cv2.normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) with NORM_MINMAX and output type of cv2.CV_8U. Or you can divide the image by 256 and cast it to np.uint8

Comment: @api55 Can't confirm. Having a 16-bit `image` (type `np.uint16`), I can use `cv2.imshow(image)` without any problems seeing a proper output (WIndows 10, Python 3.8.1, OpenCV 4.1.2). It'd be interesting what the minimum and maximum values in the original image are. Maybe, they're just to small to see a difference in the window created by `cv2.imshow`!?

Comment: @api55 `imshow` will internally divide the image by 256 in case of 16-bit images. That shouldn't be a problem. Still wondering what the image is supposed to look like.

Comment: @M.Spiller i have updated the question to the image link

Comment: @HansHirse my bad, probably got changed at some version and I didn't follow... However it will display an image divided by 256, so if it is with low values it will show  a black image. Does the pixels represent something else (for example temperature in a thermal image) ? it is to try to understand why the values are low. The loaded image has values from 23-30

Comment: @api55 yes it's a thermal image and the pixels represent the temperature

Comment: @rehan The min is 5903, the max is 7883. Both are far away from 65535, that's why they appear "black", but actually it's a very dark gray. Also, the contrast is very low with respect to the range `[0 ... 65535]`. So, use the min/max normalization as suggested above.

Comment: ahhhhhhhh, that explains everything :) The values goes from 5903-7883 in the image, that will give an almost black image. To display thermal images I would recommend to use normalize  and then you can use applycolormap with jet to get cold-> blue, hot->red.... you may need to normalize it manually to obtain a fixed temperature range

Comment: What they said...

Comment: @api55 could you show me a running example in an answer. that would help me in understanding. Also would i have to change the min/max for each image as i have around 1500 images? and how can i detect the min/max in that case? i would appreciate a full answer

Comment: give me 5 minutes and I post an answer, do you know the conversion formula from raw pixel value to celsius?

Comment: @api55 T[C]= pixelvalue [16bit] * 0.04[K] - 273.15[K]

Answer (score 2):

As you stated before, loading is easy:

```
img = cv2.imread("a.tif", cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

Then, one has different options to visualize a thermal image. The simple naive approach is to normalize from the min to the max value:

```
normed = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

[image]

After, you can color it with a colormap:

```
color = cv2.applyColorMap(normed, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
```

[image]

My suggestion would be to fix the temperature range and clip the rest of the values to get an image with colors that can be compare between several images or video. To do that, you can take the idea from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808) assuming your new min and max are 0 and 255 and your old min and max are the range you need.

To be more specific, in your case you need something like:

```
def normalizeImg(low, high, img):
    imgClip = np.clip(img, low, high)
    maxVal = np.max(imgClip)
    minVal = np.min(imgClip)
    return np.uint8((255.)/(maxVal-minVal)*(imgClip-maxVal)+255.)
```

Where low and high are the raw values you want to normalize to. And then you use it like:

```
def celsiusToPixel(val):
    return (val + 273.15) / 0.04

rangeToUse = [celsiusToPixel(20), celsiusToPixel(30)] # from 20-30° celsius
normed_range =  normalizeImg(rangeToUse[0], rangeToUse[1], img)
```

[image]

I hope a didn't miss anything, but if you have questions, just ask :)

Comment: just one small question.so for now i just want to have the normalized image which is the first image you posted but how can i normalize and save all the images at once so that i can visualize them in some software? would the same parameters work on all images? i would appreciate a small snippet.
Also a comment on colored images. if you notice there is a man sitting on chair adjacent to standing man which disappears after you apply colors. How the parameters can be tweaked to ensure that nothing of that sort happens?